# Magento has stopped sending newsletters and gives a fatal error (was working fine, it's not a cron issue either as cron is working fine)

Tags: magento, newsletter

As the title suggests, Newsletters have stopped sending. They just stick at sending 0. 
Newsletters were previously working fine for 9 months.

I've searched the net and stackoverflow for answers but nothing matches this exact problem.

The only changes has been a new theme that I have installed, however I put this on the dev server first and for testing and the newsletters still run from the dev server which was a complete clone of the code and database, so I don't think the theme is the problem. Also, I have tried switching back themes and still they don't send.

Sometimes when I run the cron.php manually I get

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addQueueData() on a non-object in /home/hairplan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php on line 193
```

And if I try to push the newsletter manually I also get the same error.

and also in the exception log I get this stack trace:

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /home/hairplan/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /home/hairplan/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /home/hairplan/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /home/hairplan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(384): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 /home/hairplan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php(185): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send('raya.wootton@uk...', 'Raya Wootton', Array)
#4 [internal function]: Mage_Newsletter_Model_Queue->sendPerSubscriber(20)
#5 /home/hairplan/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(454): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /home/hairplan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php(70): Varien_Data_Collection->walk('sendPerSubscrib...', Array)
#7 [internal function]: Mage_Newsletter_Model_Observer->scheduledSend(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#8 /home/hairplan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(111): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /home/hairplan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1265): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/hairplan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/hairplan/public_html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#12 /home/hairplan/public_html/cron.php(44): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#13 {main}
```

I recognise that the Fatal Error given means that the newsletter has failed and cannot log a reason why as for some reason it is having problems with addQueueData() or more directly the variable $queue ?

So it's down to the stack trace for the real problem behind that. From what I can see it always throws a problem with the same email address? There is no others mentioned? We have also had bouncebacks before from this exact email address? Is this related or coincidental (highly as there is ~2500 recipients).

Any help or pointers would be massively appreciated as I seem to have come to a dead end.

Mage version is 1.5.01

Many thanks

Steve

UPDATE:

Ok, it appeared that all subscribers after 1840 were throwing errors, as when I deleted one, the error moved on to the next consecutive subscriber.

To attempt to remedy this, I have dropped all the subscribers, and then started to re-add them 100 at a time (mass subscription seems to be very slow and times out at 60 seconds if using too many subscribers).

I got to 400 subscribers and thought I'd give it a test run.

Now I'm getting no errors at all either from cron or from a manual push to send, however they are still not sending! Count is staying at ZERO  :(

Now there is no stack trace or anything to go from. Zip, Zilch in the way of tracing an error.

Comment: if you try with php mail() function does it sends ? I believe that is the send service that stopped working properly.

Comment: Hi Christophe

All other emails are sending fine? Password refresh requests, contact form, order updates etc? If the send service was at fault wouldn't these also cease to function?

Comment: I think it would stop as well. I am not specialist on that question but isn't the amount that disturbs more than the email address you speak about. eg : the email is the 2000th or 1500th and there is a limitation on the server ?

Comment: No, the Mage install is set to send 20 at a time, and it doesn't even begin. There are no limitations on the server either. Also the user is 1857 on the list. So I don't understand why it would stop instantly? If it got to 1856 and stopped I could understand this maybe?

Comment: I don't understand. does it send newsletters and stop on that address or does not send at all ?

Comment: It isn't sending any at all, it;s just giving the error on that email address. However I have just deleted that email from the subscriber list and it has thrown and another email address now as the permanent error. And then the same again. These error address's are all 18** in the list. The last newsletter that succesfully sent was 2100~ subscribers, and all went without a hitch. So these email addresses have been sent to before without a problem. What doesn't make sense is why now? And why not :)  ??

Comment: I will still have closer look on the email service. as I don't have 1.5 installed anywhere and the sources changed (with line numbers), I cannot really help you on the code but you can try setting some "checkpoints" to see how looks the data.